# How to convert list to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

If i have

```
a = [['a','b','c'],['b','c','d'],['a','b','c'],['e','f','g'],['b','c','d']]
```

how do i get

```
a = {('a','b','c'):2,('b','c','d'):2,('e','f','g'):1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Counter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter(map(tuple, a))
```

Comment: @user1870662: there are many ways. `Counter` is the most consice. [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13673255/edit) to specify any additional requirements that you have.